# async waterfall getting Typeerror, nextcallback is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

```
async.waterfall([1,2,3,4].map(function (arrayItem) {
        return function (lastItemResult, nextCallback) {
            // same execution for each item in the array
            var itemResult = (arrayItem+lastItemResult);
            // results carried along from each to the next
            nextCallback(null, itemResult);
        }}), function (err, result) {
        // final callback
    });
```

so i am new to async and trying a simple example but getting this error, what is wrong with this method TypeError: nextCallback is not a function

what is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) the signature of a first function should be `function (callback)` and not `function (arg1, callback)`.

You can patch your function this way.

```
return function (lastItemResult, nextCallback) {
    if (!nextCallback) {
      nextCallback = lastItemResult;
      lastItemResult = 0;
    }

    // same execution for each item in the array
    var itemResult = (arrayItem+lastItemResult);
    // results carried along from each to the next
    nextCallback(null, itemResult);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a peek at the [async docs](https://github.com/caolan/async), you will notice the following example for `async.waterfall`:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
});
```

Compare this example with your code: the problem is that the first function that your `map` callback is generating has the wrong signature, as it should take only one argument.

When `nextCallback(null, itemResult)` is invoked, `nextCallback` is undefined.